# Currency Dollar Sign: Better to concatenate in an SQL query, or use PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I heard somewhere that it's better to have the server perform tasks, such as concatenation, but does that also apply to aesthetic stuff as well? How about using *FORMAT(val, 2)* vs *NUMBER_FORMAT(val, 2)*?

It seems like double the work, because I will still need to fetch the non-concatenated value(s) to perform other calculations, like getting the sum of all rows.

```
i.total AS total,
CONCAT('$', FORMAT(i.total, 2)) AS nice_total,
... etc


$sum_total = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $sum_total += $row['total']; #calculate sum of all rows
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['nice_total']; ?></td> <!-- Example 1 -->
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
<tr>
    <td>$<?php echo NUMBER_FORMAT($sum_total, 2); ?></td>
</tr>
```

VS

```
i.total AS total,
... etc


$sum_total = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $sum_total += $row['total']; #calculate sum of all rows
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>$<?php echo NUMBER_FORMAT($row['total'], 2); ?></td> <!-- Example 2 -->
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
<tr>
    <td>$<?php echo NUMBER_FORMAT($sum_total, 2); ?></td>
</tr>
```

I only have 4 fields to fetch with a similar structure (subtotal, tax1, tax2, total), but to fetch the same column twice for concatenation (or even formatting) feels wrong, especially if I have tons of rows; i'm just not sure how to measure the pros/cons. I do like to keep my logic as close together as possible, if that matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It seems like double the work, because I will still need to fetch the non-concatenated value(s) to perform other calculations, like getting the sum of all rows."

Go with your gut here.  Why make the DB server work when you can just echo the "$" as you are in your plain HTML?  The only thing I that might be wrong with the 2nd approach is that you'll have a "$" printed regardless of whether or not there is an actual value yielded by $row['total'] ...

Comment: I suppose I could fix that with a ISNULL(total, 0) or something, but yes, I think I will avoid cluttering my queries. Thanks!